# Find number of occurrence of a word in a 2D matrix of Characters

Tags: algorithms

Given a two dimensional matrix of alphabets, search the given word in all directions. Below is an example to search for the word `"TEAM"`:

No of occurrences is 4 in matrix below.

[image]

What is the best approach to solve this?
Its not a dictionary word. Its simply sequence searching in all the directions.

Comment: Your example does not cover corner cases where multiple occurences overlap (what about a palindromic "TEAMEAT" sequence in the matrix?). If multiple solutions exist, do you want to produce them all or only one?

Comment: all of them..above is just example. no palindromic sequence only that word.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar time ago. You should take advantage of the fact that words are a ordered set of characters. So, you perform a linear search over the matrix for the first letter, then you recursively call the directional search.

To simplify computational complexity you can add some constraint, eg, `if word.length > number of characters on that direction don't start searching`.

The recursive function signature would be like:

```
boolean search(string word, int direction)
```

with terminal case

```
if (word.length==1) return isNextLetterInDirection(word, direction);
```

and the search being

```
search(substring(word, 0, word.length-1), direction);
```

This algorithm also cover palindrome cases and words including their syllables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtracking for solving this problem, proceed till you find the word completing else backtrack.

While proceed there is a constraint which to proceed in the same direction with which you started.

For example if you are going "UP" then from next character you should go "UP" Only.